# How to get the value of an input text inside the div of a nested table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have nested table below with div elements and inputs within. I want to capture and get the value of one of the input type text when the button is click. Apparently right now, using my jquery codes below can't get one of the input text with a class="name" but the first input and the textarea were able to captured. So what is the exact code to capture the value of my second input text with a class = "name" when button is clicked. Thanks, here's the details below:

**JQuery code:**

```
 $(function () {
           $('.postrep').click(function () {
               //  e.preventDefault();
               var inputs = $(this).closest('div').find('input'); //finding the inputs inside the div
               var textin = $(this).closest('div').find('textarea'); //finding the textarea inside the div

               var dataObject = {

                   Id: inputs.first().val(), // getting the first input value in the div

                   name: inputs.first('input').next('.name').val(), // How do I get this second input value?

                   reply: textin.first().val() //getting the value of the first textarea in the div
               };
             });
          });
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="mytable">  

    <tr >
        <td class="tdstyle" >

  <div style="font-weight:bold;">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name) </div> 

   <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comment) </p>
  <p > <input type="button" id="like" name="like" value="Like" /> <input type="button" class ="Reply" name="Reply" value="Replie(s)" /></p>                                                                                                                                                                                         
   <div id="divReply" class ="divrep" >
           <table>

                 <tr >

                     <td >
                         <div style="font-weight:bold;"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.name) </div> 

                     <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.reply)  </p>

                   </td>
                 </tr>

            </table>      

     <div> 
       <div class="editor-field" style="display:none; margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px">  
          <input type="text" id="comidvalue" name="id" class="id" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)" />
       </div>

       <br />
       <input type="text" id="namerep" name="name" class="name" />  <!-- I want to get the value of this -->

      <br />
      <textarea id="reply" name="reply" class="reply" ></textarea>  

         <br />

       <input type="button" class="postrep" value="Post Reply" name="butname" style="cursor:pointer" /> 

     </div>
            <br />

  </div>
        </td>       
    </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `id` selector to get value of input box

```
$('#namerep').val();
```

But make sure that you don't have multiple input with same `id`, if you have multiple `id`s then remove id and use `class="name"` only to get the input value.

You can get input value with `class="name"` using jQuery attribute selector, please see below code -

```
$(function () {
           $('.postrep').click(function () {
               //  e.preventDefault();
               //store parent div in a variable and use it at multiple places
               var $parentDiv = $(this).closest('div');
               var inputs = $parentDiv.find('input'); //finding the inputs inside the div
               var textin = $parentDiv.find('textarea'); //finding the textarea inside the div

               var dataObject = {

                   Id: inputs.first().val(), // getting the first input value in the div

                   name: $parentDiv.find('input[class="name"]').val(), //get closest div and find input with class="name"

                   reply: textin.first().val() //getting the value of the first textarea in the div
               };
             });
          });
```

Comment: thanks and it should be  name: $(this).closest('div').find('input[class="name"]').val(),

Comment: @timmack, sorry my bad .. removed `;` from the code

Comment: Why did you edit your answer? No need to complicate your codes. It was correct it just lack of .val()

Answer (score 0):

you can get

`var name= $('#namerep').val();`

Comment: why need `closest('div').find('#namerep')` if `$('#namerep')` will find the input as `id` must be unique.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar : I agree .

Comment: No, You can't use id when the element is being looped inside but instead of a class.